# Java Screen capture and paste in MS 2007 apps problem

Tags: java, ms-word, screenshot

I have written a java program to take screenshot using Robot class and copy it to clipboard using a Transferable object. Now, if I paste it in MS 2007 applications, it appears to be blurry.

Same image if pasted to paint and recopied and pasted to MS 2007 apps is clear image .Why is this happening?

**Update:**

That image is an instance of `BufferedImage`. How to convert the image format before transferring to clipboard.

The DPI for individual pastes

The image that is pasted from paint has 96dpi and image which is from clipboard (direct from my program) is 72dpi. The screen shot is somehow in 72dpi.

And the resolution of the image is small: 300 X 300 px.

After pasting in MS Word the image gets resized to some 110% and is blurry. If I reset it to 100%, the image is still blurry.

**Update:**
Here is the image
[image: Screen short of the diff images]

Comment: This sounds like a problem with Office. If you resize the image will get it better?

Comment: Can you tell us the resolution of the image? Copying it to an Office program may automatically resize it downwards based on the amount of room available etc.

Comment: I have edited the question with your answer.
Can you post a screenshot of what you see in MS Word?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Office is scaling your image (or it thinks that it has to scale the image).

Things to look into:

1. Try a different image format (PNG, JPG, BMP)
2. Try to set the resolution of the image to 72dpi. Check the documentation of your image I/O library how to do that.